# if $a^{-1}ba=b^i$ then $a^nba^{-n}=b^{(i^n)}$ for all $n$

Tags: group-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be to elements in a group such that $a^{-1}ba=b^i$ for some natural $i$.
prove that $a^nba^{-n}=b^{(i^n)}$ for all $n$.
I tried to manipulate the given expression but I didn't manage to reach the desired equality.

Comment: you mean $a^{-n}ba^{n}$ i think

Comment: it seems more reasonable but that's what written in my textbook. Do you think it's a typo?

Comment: because the way i proved, it comes out to be what i suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have $a^{-1}ba=b^i$. So multiply $a^{-1}$ and $a$ on left and right respectively to get $a^{-2}ba^2=a^{-1}b^{i}a=(a^{-1}ba)^i=b^{i^2}$. Now proceed by induction.